# CryptokiError: 0x60 key handle invalid

Tags: hsm, safenet

We are using Safenet PTK 4.2

Recently we are encountering this error intermittently:

```
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: CryptokiError: 0x60 key handle invalid    at au.com.safenet.crypto.provider.BlockCipher.rekey(BlockCipher.java:446)   at au.com.safenet.crypto.provider.BlockCipher.engineInit(BlockCipher.java:287)
```

Appreciate if anyone with similar issue to share the solution / experience. TQ